# KeyUp event not firing on releasing numeric key C# devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress, keyup, gridcontrol, datagridcolumn

I have entered a number in grid cell. But on releasing the key keyup() is not invoked. Only after pressing tab key keyup event is working. I want it in the numerickey release. How to do it. I have set
form KeyPreview =true. Still not working.

Comment: The `FORMs` `Key` events may not fire when the “grid” has focus. I would think you would need to subscribe to the grid or grid cell key events.

Comment: Not form's keyup, gridcontrol_keyup() not firing

Comment: You need to use the EditorKeyUp Event. An Editor has the focus while you are editing not the grid itself. https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Container.EditorContainer.EditorKeyUp

Comment: I tried editorkeyup() also.Only on tabkey press its working